# How do I determine all components controlling CPU frequency?

Tags: power-management, documentation, cpufreq

Two requests please:

1. Can someone tell me how I can determine all the components that are
   a) installed and b) actively controlling CPU frequency on an
   installation?
2. And separately, can someone tell me where the documentation for
   those components is?

[For context, the forum seems to be riddled with questions on the topic of "how do I set/control/limit the range of" cpu frequency, and many of them don't seem to get actual accepted answers. I have one such, so I will have to try to learn enough to work this out for myself. Unfortunately, the docs have so far mostly eluded me, and I have failed to find the "root" document, if such exists" that describes the overall concepts. So, I'm left with a system that seems to break the rules by clocking the CPU slower and slower (down to 240 MHz!) on a system that seems to be limited to 800 MHz - 2.4 GHz.]

EDIT follow up to Pilot6's comments/answer:

1. It's an Intel CPU (Core Duo)
2. The scaling driver is acpi (why would that be? what governs that decision--it's that way out of the box)
3. I tried changing scaling_min_freq, and the system overwrote it (with a value that doesn't match what the BIOS uses for "IntelSpeedStep")
4. it makes no difference whether speedstep is enabled in BIOS
5. it runs *much* slower than min_freq, which makes your final comment about hardware issue particularly interesting.
6. It slows down (per my other thread here: [CPU clock speed slows way down Dell / Intel Core Duo (Lubuntu and others)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251019/cpu-clock-speed-slows-way-down-dell-intel-core-duo-lubuntu-and-others) ) when under long term load, but seemingly without getting too hot (~65C). It also takes forever to speed back up (but it does eventually).

TIA
Toby

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? What is the CPU? How did you find out that the CPU was working at 240 MHz?

Comment: @Pilot6 yes, I'm currently using LUbuntu 20.04 (I have tried other related distros with the same results). Frequency is shown by lscpu, and corroboratively by the system slowing down to childish throughput (1 fps on youtube videos).  I intended this question to be specifically "help me to help myself", but if you're willing to have a go at the specific problem, that question is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251019/cpu-clock-speed-slows-way-down-dell-intel-core-duo-lubuntu-and-others

Comment: The management is CPU specific.

Comment: Is some powersave option is enabled in BIOS?

Comment: Most likely Core Duo is too old for `intel_pstate`.

Comment: ah, so it chooses acpi instead... That makes sense.

Comment: for doc see [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.6/admin-guide/pm/index.html). This is a very complex subject, overall.

Answer (score 2):

CPU frequency is controlled by Linux kernel. Nothing else is installed in Ubuntu.

For desktop systems two scaling drivers are usually used: `intel_pstate` for relatively new Intel CPU's or `acpi-cpufreq` for AMD and other CPU's.

`acpi-cpufreq` can be used for Intel CPU's as well.

You can check which one your system is using by

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_driver
```

For both drivers you can control maximum and minimum speeds by writing values to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_min_freq` and `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_max_freq`.

`intel_pstate` and `acpi-cpufreq` have different scaling governors.

You can check and set them in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_governor`.

For multi-core CPU's there is a policy for each core. You can set policies separately.

If your CPU is running at speed below `scaling_min_freq`, it means that this is a hardware issue. Motherboard can also control frequencies.

Comment: intel_pstate in passive mode is another one, called intel_cpufreq. Agree 240 Mhz typically = Clock Modulation. Most likely cause: thermal, but also many OEM things via BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6, thanks, comments and more info in main question

Comment: @DougSmythies Thanks for the input. It seems to be using acpi, but not responding to the controls thereof. How/why does the OS decide which to use? And how would I interact with thermal things (given it doesn't appear to be hot) and what other BIOS things (Intel SpeedStep is disabled in BIOS)?

Comment: @TobyEggitt : Suggest use Pilot6 answer and do this: first, show the list of available frequencies: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_available_frequencies`. Second pick one, about 1/2 way between min and max, say XXXXXXX. Third do this as root (sudo su in a terminal): `for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_max_freq; do echo "XXXXXXX" > $file; done`. Then does  the slow donw not occur? If yes, increase frequency and repeat. If no lower frequency and repeat.

Comment: Thanks @DougSmythies I'll give that a try. Certainly it a) ignored, and b) *overwrote* changes I made to the min_freq. (and yes, I did change both CPUs and did it as root :)

Comment: The it is BIOS who writes to these registers. There is nothing else that can be done from Ubuntu.

Comment: @Pilot6 : Agree it could be BIOS, particularly on a Dell. However, might not tlp or themald or any other thermal or power daemon do the same overwritting? I never need that stuff so am not an expert. However, I have used thermald in pstate only mode and have seen it write to max percent as its way of limiting. (I have also seen it use Clock Modulation, as a last resort, if that mode is enabled.) Hmmm... actually overwriting the min freq makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Pilot6 I tested limiting the max freq, and that seems to be effective. Also, it seems like this has reduced? prevented? the extreme slowdown too. That would point to a temperature controller, no? But it's not reporting being hot. What slows the CPU for heat? Is that an ubuntu thing (if so what?) or is that only the BIOS?

Comment: I found [acpi_thermal_pm] in a ps listing, guessing it might be that, but there's no man page for it. Does anyone know if it is controlled by thremal-conf.xml?

Comment: @TobyEggitt : Both. And no, we have not eliminated power supply inability to supply max current load as a possible culprit, which we know causes Dell to screw around with Clock Modulation. But yes, check for messages in /var/log/kern.log and/or /var/log/syslog.

Comment: @DougSmythies ... "both"? I'm missing your point on that, I'm afraid. But very interesting. I have a bunch of PSUs here, most of which aren't "right" for this machine. I will make sure to run all tests with the 130W Dell original supply and see if that makes any difference, and report back.

Comment: I was writting at the same time as you: "What slows the CPU for heat? Is that an ubuntu thing (if so what?) or is that only the BIOS?" Answer: Both. YES.YES. Only test with Dell OEM PSU. We have so very many questions here where the root issue was non-Dell Adapter. (O.K. well, not that many.)

Comment: @DougSmythies Ah, doh, yeah, got it now. Sorry! Yes, 120 @ Dell original PSU in place. Been running solidly with 1.5 GHz limit without crazy behavior. I'll reset the limit and see what if anything changes. (Pretty certain I've seen it fail with the strong PSU, but as you say, so many variables, and I've made errors before, so need to be sure)

Comment: @DougSmythies it was beginning to look like the PSU there for a moment, but now it's failed again. However, I was capturing temperatures and CPU speed, and it seems like ti had hit 80C when it slowed down. I shut the load off and it's back down to 45C, but hasn't picked up yet. So, I was wrong about it not being thermal. I'll leave my logging going to see what temp it picks back up at. So,

Comment: It picked up when both CPUs reached 43C. Going to investigate the thermal controls whatever they might be!